# Does '..' and '.' mean the same in php as it does in Linux

Tags: php, file, foreach, directory

I have failed to find an explanation of what $user == '.' or $user == '..' means in php.
I have a folder called $rooms and the code below inspects the folder for files. But I can't find a meaning to the following: if ($user == '.' || $user == '..'). I do know the two vertical lines mean 'or'. I have found this link useful but not offering a solution https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp

```
$files = scandir($room);//List files and directories inside $rooms
    
foreach ($files as $user){
    if ($user == '.' || $user == '..') continue;
        $handle = fopen("$room/$user",'r');
```

To help I am including the full loop below
$files = scandir($room);//List files and directories inside $rooms

```
foreach ($files as $user){
    if ($user == '.' || $user == '..') continue;
        $handle = fopen("$room/$user",'r');
        $time = fread($handle, filesize("$room/$user"));
        fclose($handle);
    if ((time()-$time)>20) unlink("$room/$user");
}
```

Comment: In PHP? Nothing. For linux filesystems? `.` is the current directory and `..` is the parent directory.

Comment: Seems like file system is being used as a database. See first user contribution on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php and you don't need that conditional at all.

Comment: I did not know until now that if I can't find an answer for a php issues I should consider trying searching the same instruction as a possibly a Linux issue. Searching with the Linux keyword instead of the Php word. I will leave the question stand even though it has already been answered as a Linux question.

Answer (score 2):

On linux if you list any directory, the listing will always include a pseudo-file `.` and `..`. The single `.` is the current directory, so you can for example execute `ls .` and it will list the contents of the current directory. The two dots `..` means 'the directory above this one', so `ls ..` will list the contents of the parent directory.

This script ignores these pseudo/fake files since it is only interested in real files